# How do you set where specific components go in a GridLayout in Java?

Tags: java, user-interface, grid-layout

I am making a simple GUI and I want to put them in a GridLayout like this

areaLabel, sAreaLabel, volumeLabel

areaField, sAreaField, volumeField

blank, radiusLabel, blank

blank, radiusField, blank

so the layout would be made like this
''' 
new GridLayout(4, 3);
'''
I know how to use the The problem is that I don't know how to put components into specific places. I looked through the Java API and just online but I couldn't find anything. Do I just need to add blank components in the places I've indicated or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html

Answer (score 0):

The order of the components is defined by the rows, columns, grid orientation and the order you add the components.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html

You could add blank JLabels as placeholders for the blank cells.  Something like

```
JLabel blank = new JLabel("");
myGrid.add(blank);
```